Cypress - iframe in iframe
I have a problem with my app. I am trying to type in an element that is in two iframes.
First I´m trying to load first iframe and type in elements that are visible - it works perfect!
cy.frameLoaded('iframe');
cy.enter('iframe').then(getBody => {
            cy.wait(2000);
            getBody().find('input[data-bind="value: name"]').type("Název");
            getBody().find('textarea[data-bind="value: perex"]').type("Perex");
});

After that there is one last element that is in new iframe and I can´t type in it. If I inspect that element it shows me this:

If I try this in Cypress, it´s still not working and Cypress can´t type in it:
cy.frameLoaded('iframe'); 
        cy.enter('iframe').then(getBody => {
            cy.wait(2000); 
            getBody().find('input[data-bind="value: name"]').type("Název");
            getBody().find('textarea[data-bind="value: perex"]').type("Perex");
        
            getBody().find('iframe.k-content').iframe().then(getEditorBody => {
                const editorContent = getEditorBody.find('body[contenteditable="true"]');
                cy.wrap(editorContent).click().type("Zde bude váš text.");
            });
            getBody().find('button.btn.btn-default').click();
        });

I´m using Kendo components if it helps.
Is there some way to solve this?
Thanks for all answers!
